# ckeditor with drupal custom form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ckeditor

I created my own module form which include address textarea

```
    $form['address'] = array(
    '#input_format' => '1',
    '#rows' => '5',
    '#weight' => '4',
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Address'),

);
```

when i run the form i got the following help below it

CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is customers/edit/5.edit-address.

so i got the element ID and entered it in the include setting of the ckeditor

but still the editor doesn't appear on that field, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

use a #type of "text_format" with a #base_type of "textarea" and it should work. like this:

```
    $form['address'] = array(
      '#input_format' => '1',
      '#rows' => '5',
      '#weight' => '4',
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#base_type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => t('Address'),

  );
```

Comment: i did what you said but the editor didn't show up, still the same textarea, any other suggestion ?

Comment: I use the WYSIWYG module for all my needs. With that I'll attach an editor to the filtered HTML text format. So when you're using this textfield with a #type parameter of 'text_format' and it gives you the options of filted or full html (by default) and thus showing the editor.

Comment: I vaguely recall a `'#wysiwyg' => true` option that may help but am having a hard time searching for it.  There's a reference to it being supported in ckeditor [here](http://drupal.org/node/824822#comment-3089648), in the context of setting it false to prevent ckeditor from appearing, so maybe setting it to true will help you.

Comment: Do you have the editor working on other parts of your website (node forms, comments...)?

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks! One thing to be aware of is that in your form submission you have to grab the ['value'] part of the textarea in your form since the WYSIWYG is actually an array containing a 'value' and 'format' indices.